# how to access properties in the test attribute of a struts if tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, iterator

I'm iterating over an array of beans called 'classifications'.  How do I access the parentID property within the  tag? I tried %{parentID} but that does not work.

```
<s:iterator value="classifications" status="theStatus">
    <s:if test="%{parentID} == -1">
        <p>-1: <s:property value="subjectName" /></p>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <p>not -1: <s:property value="subjectName" /></p>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do Struts2, but in normal JSP EL the expressions are only evaluated **inside** the curly braces. It also makes sense. E.g. `<c:if test="${parentID == -1}" />`. See if it helps to do the same in your Struts2 tags. A quick glance in [their documentation](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.9/docs/tag-syntax.html) learns me that this should indeed be the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to something like this this:

```
<s:iterator value="classifications" status="theStatus" id="c">
    <s:if test="#c.parentID == -1">
        <p>-1: <s:property value="#c.subjectName" /></p>
    </s:if>
    <s:else>
        <p>not -1: <s:property value="#c.subjectName" /></p>
    </s:else>
</s:iterator>
```

Depending on what version of struts you are using you may need to change the id attribute to var in the iterator tag.